# How to set meta tag to fit screen as min-width of my page?

Tags: css, mobile, meta-tags, mobile-website

I am looking for the meta tag to set the mobile screen to fit to the size of my content.

My webpage min-width is "750px" so while loading initially it will show only one part of the screen , but when I tap to zoom out it will zoom out and fit the screen.
How can I set this behavior as default .?

Answer (score -1):

You have to set meta viewport content: `<meta name="viewport" content="">`
[Here you can read more](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/) about it and how to set it to fit your requirements.

May this fit your requirement:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

Comment: NO , I don't want the device width i want eh device to set as the content width, i tried `content="width=750"` but this also doesn't work

Comment: You have to use `content="width=750px"`  The unit is important.

Comment: NO , its just the number see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag